# Running an app built with Play in IntteliJ gives error on Maven dependency: Package not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'am using IntelliJ with Maven and Play framework.

Made a small app. Using maven to include a dependency. Compiles fine - but dependency gives an error when running: "Error: Package not found"

So, I suspect that the dependency jar must be copied to another folder in order to work? But how and where? Did expect maven to do this automatically? (I have tried to run a maven install)

**POM.XML**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ektorp</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.ektorp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Error message in IntelliJ :**
[image]

Comment: Copied all dependencies to \target\lib - but that didn't help
Question is: where should the jar files be located to be used by the Play2 runner?

Comment: One of Maven's big advantages is to NOT having to copy dependencies around. Please add the content of your `pom.xml`. How do you compile? When/where did the error occur exactly? Please add the complete error message.

Comment: Question updated with pom.xml and screenshot of the error message

Comment: Your app is most certainly not compiling fine - 49 errors? Please post the entire contents of your POM instead of just a two-point dependency snippet. Change names to protect innocent of course.